# Does it make any difference if a virtual method is declared virtual in the subclass?

Tags: c++, overriding, virtual

Quite often I see code (e.g. [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/122-virtual-functions/)) where the override is also declared virtual even if the class is not meant to be subclassed again. E.g.

```
class A {
    virtual void foo();
}
class B : public A {
    virtual void foo();
}
// there is no subclass of B (and most likely there will never be one)
```

In my naive C++ beginners thinking, I find it much clearer and more explicit not to declare `B::foo` virtual in case it is not meant to be overridden. I.e.

```
class B : public A {
     void foo();
}
```

Many methods I write are not meant to be overridden. On the other hand I understand `virtual` as indication that the method was designed to be overridden. I guess it is just a matter of taste, however I am not 100% sure:

**Does it make any difference if `B::foo()` is declared `virtual` (assuming `B` will not be used as base class)?**

Comment: No, `foo` will automatically be `virtual` in `B` since it was in `A`. It doesn't hurt to leave it there though. Especially if someone wants to derive from `B`, then they know `foo` is `virtual` without having to walk up the inheritance.

Comment: Putting an `override` in will actually force the compiler to check it at least.

Comment: As @CoryKramer said, it's not needed, but it also doesn't hurt and is good for readability and documentation for others.

Comment: @CoryKramer so it wouldnt make a difference for a subclass whether I explcitly put `virtual` in `B` or not? If this is true, maybe I should change my habit and always put the `virtual` also in the subclass....

Comment: @juanchopanza Indeed it is a duplicate. However, I think I managed quite well to ask for "good style" and getting good answers without making the question too broad or opinion based. I think this aspect is not covered in the duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no requirement to mark an overriden virtual method `virtual` in a derived class. The decision whether a method is virtual or not is made in the least derived class.

It is, however, a good idea to mark a virtual method explicitly `virtual` in a derived class for two reasons:

1. It serves as documentation for future readers of your code. That could be you, so this should be a strong incentive.
2. If someone decides to remove the `virtual` qualifier in the base class, a compiler can catch the bug before the application ships, and issue a warning. There is no requirement for a particular implementation to issue a diagnostic in this case, though.

---

If your compiler supports C++11, using the [override specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) in derived classes is recommended, as it performs additional validation. It is required for an implementation to issue an error, if a base class method is not declared `virtual`, but the derived class uses an `override` specifier.

Comment: I think sounder advice since C++11 would be to use `override`.

Comment: the compiler check you mention as 2. works without `override` (and pre C++11), right?

Comment: i guess you mean the compiler complaining about a method being `virtual` when the method that gets overridden is not `virtual`

Comment: @tobi303: I have updated the answer to address your questions.

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't make any difference. If `A::foo` is declared as `virtual` in the base class, `B::foo` is also virtual: whether you declare it as such or not.

Answer (score 2):

A method doesn't lose is `virtual` qualifier, so if `A::foo()` is virtual, `B::foo()` is also `virtual` even without repeating the keyword in `B::foo()` declaration.

Before `override`, it may be a style to repeat `virtual` in derived classes to remember that it is a overridden method, now we can use `override` instead (and compiler check that it is correct whereas it can't do it simply with `virtual`)

> Many methods I write are not meant to be overridden

So you may mark them as `final` to forbid the method to be overridden (you may also mark the class final if it makes sense).

Comment: I know `final` from java and I always liked it that it is much easier in java to express that a class is not meant to be overridden. Unfortunately I have to work "pre C++11"